# Equivalent of R's factor function in Pandas

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame called **accidents** which contains a column called **Accident_Severity**, this column contains int numbers from 1 to 3.
[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JFKp.png)

I want to change these numbers to values 'fatal', 'serious', 'slight' respectively and assign the result to a new data frame.
In R it would be something like this:
`severity <- factor(accidents$Accident_Severity, levels= c(1, 2, 3), labels= c("fatal", "serious", "slight"), ordered=TRUE)`

Comment: start here? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

accidents = pd.DataFrame({
  'Accident_Severity': [1, 2, 3, 1]
  })
di = {
  1: 'fatal',
  2: 'serious',
  3: 'slight'
}
accidents2 = accidents.replace({"Accident_Severity": di})
```